# Difference between Matplotlib methods used to label axis and title

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with Matplotlib and I came across the following two methods used to label axes and I was wondering if there are any significant differences between them since they both seem to perform same tasks. And if there is a difference is one preferred over the other.

```
ax.set_xlabel('x_axis')               

plt.xlabel('x_axis')
```

Similarly,

```
ax.set_title('title')

plt.xtitle('x_title')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to using matplotlib: a pyplot interface, and an object-oriented interface, as explained here
https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/

You can consult the following answer for explanation of why the OO approach is preferred (i.e. the first of your two options) [Why use the object oriented approach in matplotlib for visualizing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69526995/why-use-the-object-oriented-approach-in-matplotlib-for-visualizing-data)